# Converting a string to an integer in oracle

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I am trying to parse a column of strings in Oracle (version 8i) to an integer.

I am accessing the results through Oracle.DataAccess library

I'm already using `TO_NUMBER` with a mask to convert the string into a number with no decimal places. The problem is that the value in the *client code* is being retrieved as a decimal rather than an int.

Comment: why did you tag with "C#" and "odp.net"? If it's an Oracle question, you don't need those tags. If it's a C# question, you can convert a string to an int using int.Parse("42");

Comment: I guess it is not a C# question so i suggest you reedit your question and remove the C# tag

Comment: it is an ODP.Net question as the problem I have is the type that is returned within the DataTable created by the Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter is a decimal rather than an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUMBER columns always come back as decimals in ODP.NET. To get around this, pull it back as an OracleDecimal, which has several "Toxxxx" methods to cast the value into the native .NET type you need.

```
while (myOracleDataReader.Read())
{
    int x = myOracleDataReader.GetOracleDecimal(0).ToInt32();
}
```

(Forgive me if the code above isn't 100% correct, as I don't have ODP.NET installed at home.)

Answer (score 11):

```
CAST(field AS integer)
```

Comment: This one returns a .Net Decimal type yet.

Answer (score 1):

[TO_NUMBER](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) is what you want, specifically the `TO_NUMBER('42', '99')` version.

Comment: Just tried this, although the values within Oracle are integers. The output into the DataTable is still a decimal.

Comment: This one returns a .Net Decimal type yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn the decimal into an integer using the round function (or the trunc or floor functions)